# "unintentionally" or "unintendely"?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

> She was **unintentionally** inaccurate.
>
> She was **unintendedly** inaccurate.

Which one is the better choice/more idiomatic?

Comment: You should look into the definitions of [*intent*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/intent) and [*intend*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/intend), then add what is unclear. To me it is possibly *on purpose* vs. *by mistake*.

Answer (score 1):

The first is the better choice. But oh that double negative! Being intentionally inaccurate is **deception**.

> She did not intend to deceive.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely say "unintentionally." I've never heard anyone say "unintendedly." If that's a word, it sounds really antiquated.

I'm not sure that I agree with the other answer that says a double negative is bad in this case. Double negatives can make things confusing, but as a native speaker, I don't find your phrase confusing. Depending on the context, I think it could be very appropriate, in fact.